# In Localizable, ViewController.xib's link broken

Tags: iphone, ios, localized

I'm making iphone app using XCODE 4.2.

I would like to make a localized apps.

I moved the project folder. And then files(related localization)' link  is broken.

I use to move folder often.

How can I do? please tell me.... thank!~

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Select the xib marked in red
- open the File Inspector (View - Utilities - File Inspector)
- change "Full Path" to new location

Comment: Thanks your reply. ^^ but, I can't edit "Full Path". The Xib file's location is "Absolute Path". Can I change location? ^^*

Comment: there is a little arrow pointing to the right, click that and a finder window will open